# Java error :- "no suitable method found for sort(Student[],j)"

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Hello guys I am new to java programming and while practising I encountered an error please help me solve this problem which I have stated above (title). I am also attaching my code here please fix this issue and thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
class Student{
    public int marks;
    public String name;
    public Student(int marks, String name){
        this.marks = marks;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Name: " + this.name + " Marks: " + this.marks);
    }
}
public class j implements Comparator<Student>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2){
        if (o1.marks < o2.marks)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] array = new Student[2];
        array[0] = new Student(10, "varun");
        array[1] = new Student(20, "gupta");
        Collections.sort(array, new j());
        for (Student i : array)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.sort`. Also, your comparator is not transitive: `compare(s, s)` returns `-1` (comparing a student with themself).

Comment: `Collections.sort` is used to sort `List`s. `array` is not a `List` - instead it is an array as the name might suggest.

Comment: Can you provide me the code (Updated one) will be very helpful and easy for me to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change Collections.sort(array, new j()); to Arrays.sort(array, new j());